# Is every finite dimensional subspace of metric vector space (not normed) closed?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

we know that a finite-dimensional subspace of a normed vector space is closed.

Is it true for vector space with metric not induced by a norm?

Comment: What's the difference between a metric vector space and a normed vector space?

Comment: There’s a reason it is called “normed vector space”. A norm is a translation invariant absolutely homogeneous metric. So if you say “metric vector space”, do you mean a vector space with just any metric on it?

Comment: @masiewpao  I have edited the question; I hope it is more clear

Comment: @JackLeGrüß  I have edited the question; I hope it is more clear

Comment: @masiewpao $\Bbb R^\omega$ is a metric linear space that is not normable ( has no compatible norm). Metric is much more general than normed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you! I had never come across metric vector spaces since it's always been in the context of a norm (or at least a metric that induces a norm)

Answer (score 0):

Over $\mathbb{R}$ we define the distance:
$$d_{\tanh}(x,y) = \left| \tanh(x) - \tanh(y)\right|$$

$\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, we endow it with
metric $d_{\tanh}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ is 1-dimensional subspace but not closed.

but $(\mathbb{R},d_{\tanh})$ is not a complete metric space.